# Microsoft Flow - Get email body content from another list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

SharePoint Online: Is there any way to load email body content from another list (lets say EmailTemplate list), where I can manage multiple body content like below screenshot and I choose which body content has to go as email body in the flow? Is it possible ?

[image]

Appreciate your help..!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve... I thought you can use the action getitems from a list and then do whatever you want to further please provide more details.  You can get one item also and send use the description field in the email body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps below, I assume your list structure is as below

[image: email template list]

So you can follow below steps to get the email template from List.
I have used `Get Items` Action assuming you will have to fetch email template dynamically. you can replace Filter query OR make it more dynamic using variable. If its not dynamic then you can also use `Get Item` action instead of `Get Items` because this will increase the complexity of your Flow

[image: get email template]

**Update** the filter query in image needs correction it should be

Title eq 'Comment Received'